# Simple graph visualisation for C terminal application

Tags: c, graph, terminal, visualization

I need to display graphs (edges, nodes) for debugging purposes in my C terminal application.
What's the simplest way to do it? Is there anything I can use to visualise the graphs directly into the terminal?

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux I would suggest using [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) (which might also work on some other OSes). You could generate a `.dot`  file and run something to display the graph. That could be a script transforming that `.dot` file into something else then displaying it.

Comment: I already checked Graphviz out, but I wish there would be something a little more direct than writing a dot file, reading it back with the library, render the file to a image and then visualise it

Comment: It is the simplest thing to do and it works very well, especially for debugging purposes...